# SpeechSynthesis - Onend fires before speech is ended

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I want to create a similar page to GoBarbara.com from back in the days. 
There a textfield's content will be transformed from text-to-speech.

Therefore I want to use the SpeechSynthesis API (javaScript), which does text to speech after an *intro.mp3* is fired. After playing the speech, the *end.mp3* should be played.
This is handled by *Eventlisteners* of the type of "onend" at the end of intro.mp3 and the speech.

The basic trigger scheme to play audio is 1 -> 2 -> 3.
Where 1 is intro.mp3, 2 is the speech and 3 is end.mp3.

My current code is the following:

```
function doSpeech() {
   var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
   speech.text = getText();
   speech.lang = "en-US";
   speech.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {return voice.name == 'Google UK English Male'; })[0];     
   speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
   speech.onend = playEnd();
}
```

To trigger the end.mp3, I want to use the SpeechSynthesis owned *onend* event.
But onend fires the end.mp3 before the actual speech is ended!?

It seems this could be a bug. But otherwise, how do I have the mp3 starting properly after the text has been spoken out until the end? Note: The speech part can be different in length.

Comment: I had a similar problem with onstart which was solved by reversing the event and speak lines - try that?

Answer (score 1):

The proper code is

```
function doSpeech() {
   var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
   speech.text = getText();
   speech.lang = "en-US";
   speech.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {return voice.name == 'Google UK English Male'; })[0];     
   speech.onend = playEnd();
   speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

with `onend` before `speak`

Comment: Hey Nikolay, I tried that but unfortunately I get an overlap of the speech and mp3 start when using longer strings...

Comment: It seems that you’d have use `speech.onend = playEnd` without the parentheses, otherwise the function gets called straight away